# Iterate through a list, divide values, store in new list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

In the code I have series of lists, each one containing the same number of entries. What I want to do now is iterate through the list and divide one list index by the other.

```
threads = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dsk_indpt_PI = [99, 197, 295, 387, 391, 406, 407, 416, 424, 426, 425, 439]

avg_val = []
for x in threads:
    result = dsk_indpt_PI[x]/threads[x]
    avg_val.append(result[x])
```

I am unsure if the above method works, previous methods I ran into the issue where it could not do division between type int and type list. Would the above example work better? If not, what should be changed to have it function as desired? Thank you.

Comment: If you iterate over a list, you obtain the **values**, not the **indices**.

Comment: You probably want to use `xrange(len(threads))` in the `for` loop for the result you're looking for.

Comment: Therefore, I need to iterate through the indices in the list, not the list itself?

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this is to use `zip`.

You can try this:

```
avg_vals = []
for thread, dsk_ind in zip(threads, dsk_indpt_PI):
    avg_vals.append(dsk_ind / thread)
```

`zip` takes two (or more) iterables and combines them into one list of tuples with length equal to the shortest iterable.

Answer (score 2):

If you iterate over a list you obtain the **values** of the list, **not** the indices.

You can use `range(len(..))` to obtain the indices. Furthermore the result is `result`, not `result[x]` to store it into the `avg_val`:

```
avg_val = []
for x in range(len(threads)):
    result = dsk_indpt_PI[x]/threads[x]
    avg_val.append(result)
```

But a more Pythonic version will use **`zip`**:

```
avg_val = []
for a,b in zip(dsk_indpt_PI, threads):
    result = a/b
    avg_val.append(resul)
```

and we can turn this in **list comprehension**:

```
avg_val = [a/b for a,b in zip(dsk_indpt_PI, threads)]
```

List comprehension is a way to create a list in a more elegant way by writing generator syntax between square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating over a list with a regular `for` loop, you will get the values, and not the indices. If you want the indices, you could use `for i in range(len(myList)):` which would give every index `i` in your list. Alternatively, you could use `for index, value in enumerate(myList)` if you want *both* the index and the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
threads = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dsk_indpt_PI = [99, 197, 295, 387, 391, 406, 407, 416, 424, 426, 425, 439]

avg_val = []
for x in range(len(threads)):
    result = dsk_indpt_PI[x]/threads[x]
    avg_val.append(result)

print(avg_val)
```

Object is not iterable, and you cannot use result[x] as it is not a list and is being reset every time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Use pythonic way , One line solution:

```
print([item[1]/item[0] for item in zip(threads,dsk_indpt_PI)])
```

output:

```
[99.0, 98.5, 98.33333333333333, 96.75, 78.2, 67.66666666666667, 58.142857142857146, 52.0, 47.111111111111114, 42.6, 38.63636363636363, 36.583333333333336]
```

above list comprehension is same as:

```
divide=[]
for item in zip(threads,dsk_indpt_PI):
    divide.append(item[1]/item[0])

print(divide)
```